# After Password Change in Windows: Git Authentication fails after Password Prompt

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-extensions

I am hosting a Git Server on Bonobo and I'm logging in with my windows credentials.
Lately I had to change my windows password. After doing so, I am able to log in to the Bonobo Server with my new password without any problem.
But when I am trying to pull form the server using visual studio or clone a repository using git extensions, I always get an 'Authentication failed' error.

I have done a password change many times before, and the solution was always to delete the git credentials in the windows credential manager in the control panel. After this, the git password prompt appears when pulling, cloning etc. and asks for the new password. I enter the new password and everything works fine, but not now.
No matter what I do, I always get the 'Authentication failed' error, although my credentials are correct.
I tried to reinstall all git components but that did not help either.

EDIT:
I also tried to update the password in the windows credential manager. This did not help either. 
After I delete the git credential in the manager, the password prompt appears and I can enter the new credentials, but git states that the new credentials are wrong.

Comment: Did you try simply updating the password in windows credential manager? Also, you didn't state if you succeeded in getting the password popup after removing the git entry in said crendtial manager.

Comment: Side note: When reinstalling git, your git configuration (global - set to windows credential manager) will be left intact which may explain why reinstalling didn't work.

Comment: Have you established that you can run git commands via git cli? If not, it is nothing to do with either VS or GE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
For all who have the same problem:

My password contained a '§' symbol, which git does not like.
After changing the password again, everything works fine.